# Work done in expansion of gas

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

What is the Work done when a gas is slowly released from a metallic container at high pressure into a cylinder at constant atmospheric pressure equipped with frictionless piston with the help of a stopcock ?

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics.SE! Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.